# IMagick function to cut an image into roughly equally-sized tiles

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to use the IMagick PHP wrapper to assist in chopping a specified image into a set of tiles (the number of which is variable).

In the ImageMagick documentation there is reference to the `-crop` operator accepting an optional flag of `@` that will instruct it to cut an image into "roughly equally-sized divisions" ([see here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal)), solving the problem of what to do when the image size is not an exact multiple of the desired tile size.

Does anyone know if there is a way to leverage this functionality in the IMagick PHP wrapper?  Is there anything I can use besides `cropImage()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same thing (if I'm reading your question correctly). Although it does use cropImage...

```
function slice_image($name, $imageFileName, $crop_width, $crop_height)
{
```

$dir = "dir where original image is stored";
  $slicesDir = "dir where you want to store the sliced images;
  mkdir($slicesDir); //you might want to check to see if it exists first....

$fileName = $dir . $imageFileName;

$img = new Imagick($fileName);
  $imgHeight = $img->getImageHeight();
  $imgWidth = $img->getImageWidth();

$crop_width_num_times = ceil($imgWidth/$crop_width);
  $crop_height_num_times = ceil($imgHeight/$crop_height);
  for($i = 0; $i < $crop_width_num_times; $i++)
  {
    for($j = 0; $j < $crop_height_num_times; $j++)
    {
      $img = new Imagick($fileName);
      $x = ($i * $crop_width);
      $y = ($j * $crop_height);
      $img->cropImage($crop_width, $crop_height, $x, $y);
      $data = $img->getImageBlob();

```
  $newFileName = $slicesDir . $name . "_" . $x . "_" . $y . ".jpg";
  $result = file_put_contents ($newFileName, $data);
}
```

}
}